# How to delete an image with phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova

For my app, I'm using the [Cordova CameraPreview plugin](https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview), to take pictures.

Once, a picture is taken, I get a path like this (and a 2nd one for the thumbnail, but not more):

***/data/data/com.foo.bar/files/filename.jpg***

Including the picture via

```
<img src="/data/data/...">
```

it works fine, so the path seems to be valid.

However, if I try to delete pictures, it doesn't work.

My Code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(the_path, function (result) {
    alert("I'm in");        
    result.remove(function(){
        alert("removed image");
    });
});
```

The *I'm in* alert doesn't appear, in my console (Android Studio) I get the following error:

***java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL***

Do I have to modify the URL, or what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution via trial and error.

prepending

```
file://
```

to the path, so that it looks like

```
file:///data/data/com.foo.bar/files/filename.jpg
```

worked for me. But I've no idea, if this works in iOS, too.